# Dropping data from Dataframe by condition of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, mapping

I have two pandas dataframes with timestamps. I want to drop dataframe rows if the timestamp of each is **not** between the start and end timestamp of the second dataframe. But I receive the dataframe from an excel worksheet.

e.g. first dataframe:

| no | timestamp | Value | outlet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1677585630000 | 25.98 | 10 |
| 2 | 1677612900000 | 81.31 | 10 |
| 3 | 1677589319500 | 39.54 | 21 |
| 4 | 1677614000000 | 12.34 | 21 |
| 5 | 1677613900000 | 23.87 | 10 |

e.g. Excel worksheet for outlet 10 (as a own dataframe):

| no | Start Run | End Run |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28.02.2023 13:00:00 | 28.02.2023 13:00:40 |
| 2 | 28.02.2023 14:00:00 | 28.02.2023 14:00:19 |
| 3 | 28.02.2023 20:30:00 | 28.02.2023 20:46:40 |

So in this case the result should be:

| no | timestamp | Value | outlet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1677585630000 | 25.98 | 10 |
| 2 | 1677612900000 | 23.87 | 10 |
| 3 | 1677589319500 | 39.54 | 21 |

I already wrote a code to solve the problem, but I did it with two for-loops and it tooks way to long to execute it efficiently:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime

d = {'ts': [1677585630000, 1677612900000, 1677589319500, 1677614000000, 1677613900000],
    'value': [25.98, 81.31, 39.54, 12.34, 23.87],
    'outlet_id': [10,10,21,21,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

excelPath = "./Stackoverflow/runningtimes.xlsx"

excel_dfs = []
excel_dfs_index = []

dropped = 0

# examples // Original data comes from an excel sheet
d10 = {'outlet_id': [10, 10, 10],
        'Start Run': ['28.02.2023  13:00:00', '28.02.2023  14:00:00', '28.02.2023  20:30:00'],
        'End Run': ['28.02.2023  13:00:40', '28.02.2023  14:00:19', '28.02.2023  20:46:40']}

d21 = {'outlet_id': [21, 21, 21],
        'Start Run': ['28.02.2023  13:00:40', '28.02.2023  14:01:59', '28.02.2023  20:46:40'],
        'End Run': ['28.02.2023  13:00:50', '28.02.2023  14:02:09', '28.02.2023  20:51:40']}

df10 = pd.DataFrame(data=d10)
df21 = pd.DataFrame(data=d21)

print("DF Length before: " + str(len(df.index)))

for rowIndex, row in df.iterrows():

    timestamp = row['ts']
    outlet_id = int(row['outlet_id'])

    try:
        if not outlet_id in excel_dfs_index:
            # excel_dfs.append(pd.read_excel(excelPath, sheet_name=str(outlet_id)))
            if outlet_id == 10:
                excel_dfs.append(df10)
            elif outlet_id == 21:
                excel_dfs.append(df21)
            excel_dfs_index.append(outlet_id)

        localdf = excel_dfs[excel_dfs_index.index(outlet_id)]

        wasRunning = False

        for indexEX, rowEX in localdf.iterrows():
            
            startRunTS = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(rowEX['Start Run']), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()) * 1000
            endRunTS = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(rowEX['End Run']), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()) * 1000
                
            if (float(startRunTS) <= float(timestamp) <= float(endRunTS)):
                wasRunning = True
                break

        if wasRunning == False:
            df = df.drop(index=rowIndex, axis='rows')
            dropped += 1

    except:
        if not outlet_id in excel_dfs_index:
            print("outlet not found in excel file")
            excel_dfs.append(pd.read_excel(excelPath, sheet_name=str(outlet_id)))
            excel_dfs_index.append(outlet_id)

print("DF Length after: " + str(len(df.index)))
print("Dropped: " + str(dropped))

print (df)
```

Has anyone a solution, that would be more efficient?

Comment: Could you elaborate why row with timestamp 1001052 should remain? It seems this timestamp is greater than `end_timestamp` for the corresponding `no`...

Comment: In my opinion 1001052 is between 1000821 and 1001752 (row 3). But these values are only examples ...

Comment: Fine, but 1001052 is in the fifth row and has `no` value of 1. I don't understand the logic leading to associations between the rows of df1 and df2...

Comment: In the fourth col you can see the outlet id, in this case it is 1. There is my association between df1 and df2. The outlet id is my key to get the df of the outlet. The timestamps are in a excel file where every outlet id has an own worksheet with the id as worksheet name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: adapting example after OP's edit

First you should make sure your timestamps are consistent (also I edited the first row of `df10`, otherwise the output df would be empty). Then if you build a dictionary to lookup your excel_dfs, you can use the funtion I previously submitted with a slight modification:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'ts': [1677585630000, 1677612900000, 1677589319500, 1677614000000, 1677613900000],
    'value': [25.98, 81.31, 39.54, 12.34, 23.87],
    'outlet_id': [10,10,21,21,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], unit='ms')

# examples // Original data comes from an excel sheet
d10 = {'outlet_id': [10, 10, 10],
        'Start Run': ['28.02.2023  12:00:00', '28.02.2023  14:00:00', '28.02.2023  20:30:00'],
        'End Run': ['28.02.2023  12:00:40', '28.02.2023  14:00:19', '28.02.2023  20:46:40']}

d21 = {'outlet_id': [21, 21, 21],
        'Start Run': ['28.02.2023  13:00:40', '28.02.2023  14:01:59', '28.02.2023  20:46:40'],
        'End Run': ['28.02.2023  13:00:50', '28.02.2023  14:02:09', '28.02.2023  20:51:40']}

df10 = pd.DataFrame(data=d10)
df10[['Start Run', 'End Run']] = df10[['Start Run', 'End Run']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df21 = pd.DataFrame(data=d21)
df21[['Start Run', 'End Run']] = df21[['Start Run', 'End Run']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

excel_dfs = {10: df10, 21: df21}    # lookup dictionary for your excel dfs
# in your real case you'd build it with sth like:
# {outlet_id: pd.read_excel(excelPath, sheet_name=str(outlet_id)) for outlet_id in df['outlet_id'].unique()}

print("DF Length before: " + str(len(df.index)))

def is_between_start_and_end(row_df):
    ts = row_df['ts']
    df_xls = excel_dfs[row_df['outlet_id']]
    return any(row['Start Run'] <= ts <= row['End Run'] for _, row in df_xls.iterrows())

df = df[df.apply(is_between_start_and_end, axis=1)]

print("DF Length after: " + str(len(df.index)))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                   ts  value  outlet_id
0 2023-02-28 12:00:30  25.98         10
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But maybe I don't understand what you're doing ... I understood, that I could implement it like this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/95ytnmjp/)

Comment: Why would you convert the timestamps to datetime? the comparison should work with int as well. Besides, you should post executable code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My big issue is, that I receive not timestamps, I receive a date format "dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS" and I have to transform it into a timestamp. I know maybe it was misunterstandable ...

Comment: I updated my question and it's is closer to my use case. And the code is executable. Thank you very much for your hints :)

Comment: That's better! Now column names are more consistent between your tables and code. However we don't have access to `runningtimes.xlsx`. You could change your code to avoid reading from excel and provide the running times dfs for outlets 10 and 21.

Comment: You can see the worksheet table of the excel file as the second table. But sure, I'll change so that there are df for each worksheet

Comment: Yes. But my code already works on the tables (at least before your edit). You need to provide code that reproduces the problem so that others can fix said problem (see my link above) in a way that is useful to you.

Comment: Now my code reproduces my problem exactly. Thank you for all your organizational hints, it's my first entry on stackoverflow. But maybe I understand you answer in a wrong way, so that's not working in my code ... Did you have any hints to implement it?